# Populating owlCarousel in loading multiple items of <li> dynamically via AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, owl-carousel

Here is the HTML

```
 <div id="brand-1" class="tab-panel active"><ul class="tab-products owl-carousel" data-dots="false" data-autoPlay="true" data-nav="true" data-margin="30" data-responsive='{"0":{"items":1},"480":{"items":1},"600":{"items":1},"1000":{"items":3}}'> </ul></div>
```

And the Jquery is:

```
$.ajax({
                    url: "load_carousel_by_ajax_homepage.asp?cat=1&W=200&H=240&nos_items=6",
                    async:true,
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#brand-1').owlCarousel().trigger('add.owl.carousel',  [$(data),0]).trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');

                        } 

                }); //ajax loaing
```

Though, this code works for single item,  i am not sure how to add multiple items to the owlCarousel... Any help would be appreciated.... The AJAX result of each  is as follows:

```
<li class="product-style3">TEST1</li>  
<li class="product-style3">TEST2</li> etc...
```

Comment: FINALLY IT WORKED in this way

Comment: $(#brand-1).load("load_carousel_by_ajax_homepage.asp?cat=1&W=300&H=366&nos_items=6", function() {
 $(#brand-1t).owlCarousel();    });